# Using a dict as RequestParser validation arguments

Tags: python, flask-restful

I wondered if there is a way to pass a dict to the arguments of a RequestParser .add_argument() command

it normally works like this

```
    my_parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
    my_parser.add_argument('my_field', type=dict, help='my_field must be a dict', required=True)
```

For code re-usability purposes, I'd like to use it somewhat like this

```
    my_arguments = {type=dict, help='my_field must be a dict', required=True}
```

and then pass these as arguments to the .add_argument function using:

```
    my_parser.add_argument('my_field', my_arguments)
```

I got stuck trying to do this using list comprehension,

```
    my_parser.add_arguments('my_field', list(key=value for (key, value) in parser_arguments.items()))
```

at which point I realized I probably can't use a dict, might need to do a getattr() and clearly investing too much time on this. It seems possible and elegant to me, but I can't find a solution anyway, thankful for any enlightening ideas on this.

Edit: I can't use the intuitive

```
    my_parser.add_argument('my_field', my_arguments)
```

because the dict will be added to the "default" field of the parser argument, and the actual fields ("type", "help" and "required") are unaffected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RESTful-Flask parsing JSON Arrays with parse\_args()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45613160/restful-flask-parsing-json-arrays-with-parse-args)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can use kwargs unpacking](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/understanding-args-and-kwargs-in-python--cms-29494):

```
my_arguments = {'type':dict, 'help':'my_field must be a dict', 'required':True}
my_parser.add_argument('my_field', **my_dict)
```

Which is equivalent to

```
my_parser.add_argument('my_field', type=dict, help='my_field must be a dict', required=True)
```

Comment: I swear I tried that, I must have had an error in the dict itself when I did. This obviously works perfectly.